# spinner.setSelection help

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, spinner

I'm trying to load my preferences and update a spinner to show the previously saved value. I've never used spinner.setSelection before and keep getting nullpointerexceptions.

```
String[] timeItems = new String[] {"After 2 minutes", "After 5 minutes", "Never"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
Spinner screenSpinner;
```

onCreate():

```
Spinner screenSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_screen);
        screenSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, timeItems);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        screenSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

loadPrefs()

```
    //load the preferences
...
    //then update the selection in the spinner    
    if (mScreenTimer == SCREEN_TIMER_2MINUTES) {
                    int tmp_index = adapter.getPosition("After 2 minutes");
                    screenSpinner.setSelection(tmp_index,true);
                } else if (mScreenTimer == SCREEN_TIMER_5MINUTES) {
                    int tmp_index = adapter.getPosition("After 5 minutes");
                    screenSpinner.setSelection(tmp_index,true);
                } else if (mScreenTimer == SCREEN_TIMER_NEVER) {
                    int tmp_index = adapter.getPosition("Never");
                    screenSpinner.setSelection(tmp_index,true);
                }
```

I get the NullPointerExecption on screenSpinner.setSelection(tmp_index, true)

Comment: Consider posting the full stack trace next time. It is unclear from your question if you are literally getting a `NullPointerException` on that line, or if something *inside* the call to `setSelection` is where the `NullPointerException` is. If it's the former, then `screenSpinner` is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the selection after setting the adapter